# Algorithms and data structures for comparing things and deciding how similar they are?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, compare, comparison

What **algorithms** and/or **data-structures** that can be applied **to decide how similar two things are based on some common characteristics**.

What area of knowledge deals with this type of problem?

One way of doing this could be:

** Where each int value represents some characteristic

** and each set of ints represent a group of characteristics within a feature for example

Object_1: `{1, 2, 3}, {11, 14}, {88, 90}`

Object_2: `{4, 7}, {12, 16}, {81, 91}`

Search Term: `{2, 90}`

Search should return `'Object_1'` because {`2, 90}` is subset of `{1, 2, 3, 11, 14, 88, 90}`

Hope this example narrows the question down a bit.

Comment: What do the sets in object_i represent ? Are there always three sets ? Why define sets if you don't take them in account (referring your search term). And what do the integer represent as well ?
Characteristic is too vague. Object_1 and Object_2 have not the same number of integers nor the sets have the same size wise... so we can't infer any dimension stuff

Comment: thanks @grodzi, so each set in  object_i  represent characteristic we care about for a given feature so for example the feature car-body-colour could have {red, metallic, fade} so {1,2,3} for example. So 1 will always mean 'red' etc. Can be any number of sets. The search term only cares about certain characteristics so only {2,90} but Object_i will many characteristics. These sets of ints represent characteristics that we care about now and may no longer care about in future, so we can add and remove sets of ints as time passes.

Comment: the above is just an example to help narrow the question but may not be the only/best way to solve this type of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different types of similarity measures out there. To decide which one to use the first step is to specify your [level of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) and type of data. Here are a few similarity measures for categorical and cont data:

- For categorical data:

  - Hamming distance
  - Sokal-Michener
  - Russel–Rao
- For continuous data:

  - Minkowski-based distances e.g [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)
  - [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)

The general algorithm that is used for similarity-based learning is Nearest Neighbor algorithm. For more information you can refer to [John.D Kelleher's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262044692).